# Not able to set values for radiobutton group with values returned from Apex map in lightning component

Tags: aura, map

Not sure what I am doing wrong here or maybe I have been on this for such a long time I am not seeing the issue.

I am not able to extract values of a map in js controller of lightning component. With the below code I am getting all the required values in the controller, but I am not able to extract them to put as values and labels for the radiogroup buttons. This is the way the values are displayed in the javascript side -

0123h000000UeE7AAK: "Item 1"
0123h000000kuruAAA: "Item 2"
0123h000000kv03AAA: "Item 3"
0123h000000kv04AAA: "Item 4"
0123h0000004HSyAAM: "Item 5"

Here is how I set the map in apex controller -

```
    public static Map<String, String> returnRts(String sObjectName) {
        Map<String, String> rts = new Map<String,String>();
        List<RecordType> recordTypes = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = :sObjectName];
        
        for (RecordType rt: recordTypes) {
            rts.put(rt.Id, rt.Name);
        }
        return rts;
    }


**AURA Component**
<aura:attribute name="theRecordTypes" type="map" />
<lightning:radioGroup name="theRecordTypes" variant="label-hidden" options="{! v.theRecordTypes }" type="radio" />

({
    onLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.returnRts");
        action.setParams({ 
            sObjectName : "Account" 
        });
 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var recordTypes = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set('v.theRecordTypes ', reponse.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {

            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the salesforce documentation sample radio group example, options to be of type List. In this case it is Map

change the type from Map to List

```
<aura:attribute name="theRecordTypes" type="List"  />
```

Typo error

change the line

```
component.set('v.theRecordTypes ', reponse.getReturnValue());
```

to

```
component.set('v.theRecordTypes ', response.getReturnValue());
```

Convert the map from server code to List Array

```
let rtMap = response.getReturnValue();                
var rtArray = [];
for ( var key in rtMap ) {
    let recordType = {label: rtMap[key], value: rtMap[key]};
    rtArray.push(recordType);
}                                    
                                                     
component.set('v.theRecordTypes ', rtArray);
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, that worked.